# Ruby: convert string to date

Tags: ruby, string, date

In Ruby, what's the best way to convert a string of the format: `"{ 2009, 4, 15 }"` to a Date?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3599239/1569

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You could also use `Date.strptime`:

```
Date.strptime("{ 2009, 4, 15 }", "{ %Y, %m, %d }")
```

Comment: What if the month is invalid... is there a method that return nil rather than raising an exception

Comment: @Ross: What's wrong with wrapping it in `begin` and `rescue ArgumentError` and in that case return `nil`?

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

```
s = "{ 2009, 4, 15 }"
d = Date.parse( s.gsub(/, */, '-') )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def parse_date(date)
  Date.parse date.gsub(/[{}\s]/, "").gsub(",", ".")
end

date = parse_date("{ 2009, 4, 15 }")
date.day
#=> 15
date.month
#=> 4
date.year
#=> 2009
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Date.new(*"{ 2009, 04, 15 }".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i))
```