# Ruby - convert string to date

Tags: ruby, date

I have a string like "2011-06-02T23:59:59+05:30".

I want to convert it to date format and need to parse only the date, "2011-06-02".

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times. I suggest closing as duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720907/ruby-convert-string-to-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby String to Date Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599239/ruby-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For Ruby 1.9.2:

```
require 'date'    # If not already required. If in Rails then you don't need this line).
puts DateTime.parse("2011-06-02T23:59:59+05:30").to_date.to_s
```

Answer (score 17):

```
require 'date'
d = Date.parse("2011-06-02T23:59:59+05:30")
d.strftime("%F")
```

Comment: this won't parse a timestamp with time correctly - use `DateTime.parse()` instead unless you only want to work with dates.

Comment: @AdamMcArthur..The OP specifically wanted the date part only. But, you are right. even for dates, if we omit the time part and the time zones, it can be dangerous, because it can be another day in another time zone. So, better use `DateTime.parse`.

Comment: I was rather surprised when I found out these two methods were separated when, to me, the use of `Date.parse()` outputs no different to `DateTime.parse()` when using a timestamp with date only. I can't imagine there would be any notable performance advantages of just using `Date`...

Answer (score 3):

Simplies way is

```
require 'date'
date = "2011-06-02T23:59:59+05:30".gsub(/T.*/, '')
DateTime.parse(date)
```

Comment: Or you can use `Date` instead of `DateTime` and ignore the gsub operation ;)

Answer (score 3):

Time.parse() should allow you to parse the whole date time. Then you can use time.strftime( string ) to format that as just a date in a string.

```
date = Time.parse("2011-06-02T23:59:59+05:30")
date_string = time.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
of
date_string = time.strftime("%F")
```

(see [Ruby Doc for Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392) for more output string formats)
The above should work if you want a string; if you want a date object to handle then the ruby Date class can help you handle it but I belive that everything still needs to be done with Time objects; see [Ruby Doc for Date](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html) for details of the Date class.

Hope that helps, let me know if I have headed off in the wrong direction with my answer.