# Parse Date in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I take formatted dates (like 07/11/1990) and convert them into 19900711? a regular expression and some substitution perhaps?

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214144/ruby-convert-string-to-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby String to Date Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599239/ruby-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'date'

DateTime.strptime('07/11/1990', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

works for me.

Comment: This works as well, any big difference between this `date` method and the above `time` method?

Comment: strptime has more control I guess. For example

> Time.parse('07111990') 

fails, but 

> DateTime.strptime('07111990','%m%d%Y')

still works. But as long as Time.parse works, that may be more concise way to code.

Comment: @585connor: The `strptime` approach lets you specify the date format and, given the various date formats that are in use, that might be better than guessing. OTOH, I use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for everything...

Answer (score 4):

Time class is your friend:

```
1.9.2p290 :002 > puts Time.parse('07/11/1990').strftime("%Y%d%m")
-->  19900711
```

You may need to `require "time"` for this to work though.  See string formatted time for more information on the output format.

Comment: I think that only works in most recent version of ruby, isn't?

Comment: Time has been present in every version of ruby that I've touched, dating back to 1.8.5

Comment: @Eugene I can't find Time.parse in ruby's documentation. Do you have a link? My question was: Isn't it recommended to specify the format given to the parse method to avoid the confusion between %d%m%Y (European format) and %m%d%Y (US format)?

Comment: Time inherits some of its methods from the Date class, parse is one of them.  Check the Date documentation for the parse method.  As far as I know, there is no way to change the date that it parses as.  You would have to sanitize the input before it got to the parse if you were concerned with that.

US format is the default, however you can be much more specific with the date as well.  For example, Time.parse("July 11 1990") or Time.parse("November 7 1990") are also valid.  You would just need to sanitize your input and do some conversion before you parse the time.

Comment: This behavior also looks related to locale settings of the machine you are running Ruby on.  I had some friends in the UK test this out, and their returned format is European format.  The Ruby source does not indicate a way to force one format over the other though, this will still need to be done via input sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more efficient way like `dateVar.gsub("/","")`. Ofcourse replace dateVar for the variable where you'd stored the date in.

Comment: The OP is not just removing the `/`, they are also reordering the numbers