# Rails: Convert string "04/30/2015" to valid datetime for storing inside postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, converters

Very simple question but could not find a solution or figure it out yet.

How to convert this string "04/30/2015" to valid datetime for storing inside postgres database?

I tried several ways to no avail:

```
new_date = "#{ params[:interview][:expire_at]}00:00:00".to_datetime
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: convert string to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720907/ruby-convert-string-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
Date.strptime(params[:interview][:expire_at], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

using `.to_datetime` will be reduntant at that point, considering it should exactly do what you are trying to achieve.

`"30-4-2015".to_datetime` as well as `"2015/30/4".to_datetime` will be accepted, so it would need some extra formatting to your string to work.

`.to_datetime` requires the day to be passed before the month. no matter if the year is pre- or appended, or what seperator you use, check the [examples in the apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime).

However, using `Date` appears to be more straight forward.

Comment: Worked, thank you. It really bogged my mind see the logic in your solution now after reading up the api docs for date

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
Date.strptime(params[:interview][:expire_at], '%m/%d/%Y').to_datetime
```